# Parametrized query android sqlite not working?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have two queries, one with a `?` which I substitute via the selection args and the other where the entire query has been prepared as a string. The query with `?` does not seem to return any result and neither any error.

```
String query1 = "strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABAE_STRFORMAT
                + "', "+ COLUMN_NAME_DATE_CREATED +") BETWEEN strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABAE_STRFORMAT + "', '"+ sdf.format(fromDate) +"') AND strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABAE_STRFORMAT + "', '"+ sdf.format(toDate)+"')";
```

The query above returns results as expected.

```
String query2 = "strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT
                + "', "+ "?" +") BETWEEN strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT + "', "+ "?" +") AND strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT + "', "+ "?"+")";




    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            COLUMN_NAME_DATE_CREATED,
            sdf.format(fromDate), sdf.format(toDate) };
```

Query 2 above returns no results. The `cursor` is created as shown below with the difference that for query 1 the `selectionArgs` is set to an empty array.

```
Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(database.getReadableDatabase(),
                projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that parameterized query with a `strftime` works only with the time stamps parameterized and not the column name for some reason.

So the below works

```
String whereClause = "strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT + "', " + COLUMN_NAME_DATE_CREATED
                + ") BETWEEN strftime('" + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT
                + "', " + "?" + ") AND strftime('"
                + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT + "', " + "?" + ")";

String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
        sdf.format(fromDate), sdf.format(toDate) };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     String query2 = "strftime('"
              + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT
              + "', "+ "?" +") BETWEEN strftime('"
              + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT + "', "+ "?" +"' ) AND strftime('"
              + Constants.SQLITE_DATABASE_STRFORMAT + "', "+ "?"+"' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out the spelling errors in query1 - i.e. 'DATABAE'